# Check for changes in MySQL, node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, function, mysql-event

How can I, in this code, take the data that has been changed in MYSQL and return it in another function?
For example, take the id_ticket column and use it in another function.

```
    const instance = new MySQLEvents(connection, {
      startAtEnd: true
    });
  
    await instance.start();
  
    instance.addTrigger({
      name: 'monitoring all statments',
      expression: config.MYSQL_DATABASE+'.ticket.*',
      statement: MySQLEvents.STATEMENTS.ALL,
      onEvent: e => {
        //Take column "id_ticket"
      }
    });
  
    instance.on(MySQLEvents.EVENTS.CONNECTION_ERROR, console.error);
    instance.on(MySQLEvents.EVENTS.ZONGJI_ERROR, console.error);
  };
  function idticket(//take "id_ticket" from event){

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onEvent is a handler, you just need to pass a function to that handler

```
onEvent: handler
```

and

```
function handler(event) {
  console.log('event', event)
  // do some more
}
```